# Script won't handle errors

Tags: python, error-handling, raspberry-pi, imap, daemon

I have kinda pieced together a script out of some that I have found online to do a quick "home automation" demo for proof of concept with a Raspberry Pi. I later realized it could also be used as a "no response terminal" as well. Sorry for not giving credit to the original owners of the code, as I don't remember where I even found it, and there are not credits in it to begin with.

Anyway. I have made my own changes to it, and it works great. I set it up as an upstart daemon on the pi, and it runs find and operates as it should for 2-5 days. It then will hang, somewhere in the script, and never actually executes the except: to do the error handling. Actually, 2 out of the 3 scripts that I have written and running as daemons will do this.

Here is my code.

```
import imaplib
import email
import GPIO
import subprocess
import prowlpy
import time
import sys
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('error.log')
# Configure logger to write to a file...

def my_handler(type, value, tb):
    logger.exception("Uncaught exception: {0}".format(str(value)))

# Install exception handler
sys.excepthook = my_handler

pnotify = prowlpy.Prowl(###)    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        try:
            mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
            mail.login('###', '###')

            mail.select('inbox')    
            mail.list()

            typ, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
            for num in data[0].split():
                typ, data = mail.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
            typ, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
            ids = data[0]
            id_list = ids.split()

            if id_list:
                latest_email_id = int( id_list[-1] )
                for i in range( latest_email_id, latest_email_id-1, -1):
                    typ, data = mail.fetch( i, '(RFC822)')
                for response_part in data:
                    if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
                        msg = email.message_from_string(response_part[1])
                varSubject = msg['subject']
                varFrom = msg['from']
                varFrom = varFrom.replace('<','')
                varFrom = varFrom.replace('>','')
                if varSubject == 'Lights - ON' :
                    varSubject = 1
                    GPIO.writePin(3, 0)
                    pnotify.add('RPi', 'Welcome Home', 'Notification', -2)
                elif varSubject == 'Lights - OFF' :
                    varSubject = 1
                    GPIO.writePin(3, 1)
                    pnotify.add('RPi', 'Have a nice day!', 'Notification', -2)
                elif 'CMD' in varSubject and '###' in varFrom: #REQUIRES VALIDATION
                    subprocess.call(varSubject.split("- ")[1], shell=True)
                    pnotify.add('RPi', 'CMD EXEC - '+varSubject.split("- ")[1], 'Notification', -2)
                    varSubject = 1
                else :
                    varSubject = 0 
            else: #No Emails
                varSubject = 0



            #Remove used emails from mailbox
            typ, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
            for num in data[0].split():
                mail.store(num, '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
            mail.expunge()
            mail.close()
            mail.logout()
        except:
            print "Could not establish connection or some other error... waiting 20s" 
            time.sleep(20)
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: To answer this question requires going through a lot of code. This makes it hard to give good answers without spending disproportionate amounts of time on the question; most people will rather move on to another question. If you distil the question down to the smallest possible sample that reproduces the problem the quantity, quality and clarity of answers you get will improve as well. The edited question does not have to do the same thing as the whole of the code, it only needs to reproduce the one aspect that you need help with: the random hanging.

Comment: Write debug printing to external log file and see where it gets stuck (it might not even be consistent btw...).

Comment: Thats the problem. I do have it trying to write to a log file, but it never does. When it hangs, it is seemingly random, and takes days to do so. I never get anything in the logs, and no clue as to what could even be the cause to begin with. The script executes just fine for days, so there is something changing, and I am starting to lean towards more to something to do with my pi.

Comment: strace -p might tell you.

Comment: Oh man, blast from the past. 

I sure hope I've improved on this since! (I still think it was an issue with the Pi, as I upgraded Pis and the issue went away, granted, this was years ago)